# standalone portable CMS

Tags: open-source, java, cms, portable

I want to find a CMS for backing up personal images and videos which will be large during days on a remove able storage like CD/DVD. But it should not be a simple backup, I want to organize them by tags, descriptions , links , ... . So a CMS is necessary. Some feature I think it must has:

1. Open source
2. Standalone/portable CMS to run when inserted in player (for example created by `Java` so will run on all computer which has `Java VM`)
3. Works on cd/DVD
4. Beauty gallery

Like other CMS, it must support backing up and search.

Comment: A CMS is ***not*** your only option. However, the best source of CMS infor is http://cmsmatrix.org/  You might also consider Googling for Personal Infomation Manager. A great source of rated freeware is http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-pim.htm (as is SoucreForge). And take alook at http://www.tranglos.com/free/keynote.html

Comment: Maybe you need a DMS ([tag:document-management]) instead of a CMS? Is Java required? If not, on which operating systems does it need to run? Just in case: would you also be fine with a stand-alone desktop tool (so not a Web app)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did not use `CMS`. As Steve Barnes proposed [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/25644/16285), I used [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to generate an index page with a command line. The result page can be open by all browsers.

I used `montage` command to add some details to each image thumbnail which  opens image by clicking.

```
montage -label '%t\n%[width]x%[height]' \
          -size 512x512 "../img_photos/*.*[120x90]" -auto-orient \
          -geometry +5+5 -tile 5x  -frame 5  -shadow  photo_index.html
```